# How to hardcode Jenkins job configuration file

Tags: xml, jenkins, jobs

I need to create job in Jenkins. But I don't have the configurations XML with all the plugins information with me. I want to hard-code the XML. Please help me understanding the XML sheet tags. And also please help me with a XML sheet having a demo project with few plugins like GIT, Ant, Sonarqube.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In general, **there's no documentation for the job config XML**, so it is best to proceed as follows:

1. **create a sample job manually via the GUI**, then
2. **understand that job's XML code** -- it will be easy to match it with the job's configuration.

In some rare cases, the job configuration is scattered among several XML files (one example that I'm aware of is the [Promoted Builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)). This will require special handling when operating on XML level.

Comment: It is difficult to understand the tags. So to modify the configuration file of sample file, can i have a configuration file tags explained elaborately.

Comment: No, such documentation does not exist, since the whole XML content is Jenkins-internal data. If you wonder about the meaning of a particular tag, the best will be to look that up in the source code. But normally, the whole XML file should be self-explaining if you also have access to the GUI representation of the job.